# Change image "Color Space" setting from script

Tags: scripting, image, color

I`m loading some images from script and I need to be able to change their "Color Space" setting from python. Some of the images are normal maps and it took me a while to get what was going on and how to fix that. Changing the parameter manually via Image Editor works, but I need to change it automatically.

Referring to doc: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html it seems that the name is "colorspace_settings", but appears to be read-only.

Does anybody know how I can change it? I tried browsing Blender source, but it`ll take me some time to find and understand how to do it.

Thanks for your time. :-)